# Gradle sync failed: Unable to find method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I try to import a project in Android studio. When importing it, i've got an Error with Gradle :

```
Gradle sync failed: Unable to find method 

'org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.setExtendsFrom(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration;'.
```

I have tried :

- Re-download dependencies and sync project: Fail (same error).
- Stop Gradle build processes: Fail (same error).
- Delete the .graddle in the home directory: Fail (same error).
- Invalidate cache and restart Fail (same error).
- Uninstall and reinstall Android studio and SDK: Fail (same error).

**/build.gradle :**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'xxx.xxx.xxx'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        buildPB {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false

            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
//    lintOptions {
//        abortOnError false
//    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile ('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }
    compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
//    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
}
```

Comment: Couple of things to to rule out, try clearing your build folder and stopping java in task manager, this normally fixes most gradle issues I have

Comment: Look to Build logs more attentively. In my case, I has outdated AppCenter gradle plugin

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I fixed the error by changing the following things.

1. Open the file under `your-app-project\your-app-name\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`
2. replace the old URL path by this one:
   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`
3. Rename the folder name from `"...\1.12"` to `your-app-project\your-app-name\.gradle\2.10`
4. Change the `classpath` of `your-app-project\your-app-name\build.gradle` to
   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`
5. Replace `runProguard` of `your-app-project\your-app-name\app\build.gradle` by `minifyEnabled`
6. Click Retry on the error reminder or Reopen your Android Studio and project.

I am using the latest versions of Android Studio and Gradle.

Comment: Number 2 solved my problem. The problem I had was I was opening a project in Android Studio 2.2.2 that was created in a version of android studio in version 1.0.0

Comment: 2) worked for me too. In my case, I replaced the line with:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Comment: I already have `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip` in my gradle-wrapper.properties file, but still having the same error.

Comment: It's amazing how new versions have way more problem than older ones. Long live eclipse...

Comment: I am getting the same error even though I have version `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`. how to solve this?

Answer (score 15):

edit Project >> App >> gradle >> wrapper >> gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-bin.zip
```

rebuild the project (restart ide in your mind)

Comment: Made my day. Tks

Answer (score 6):

```
Project >> App >> gradle >> wrapper >> gradle-wrapper.properties

https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

This will surely work. I was having same issue. Solved by this.

Answer (score 5):

This issue appears when I updated my android studio to 3.1.1

1.
I have resolved it by changing:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'`
in build.gradle (project)

2.
change:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`
in gradle-wrapper.properties.
(you can check it in explorer C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.4)

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue and i resolved it by
`Android Studio Version 3.0.1`

1.Change the classpath of `your-app-project\your-app-name\build.gradle` to classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'.`

2.Replace the old URL path by this one: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

My gradle file was of version 4.1
ie; file in following location:(may differ slightly in your machine)
`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1`

Answer (score 2):

Under `gradle`->`gradle-wrapper.properties`

replacing

```
distributionUrl=https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

with

```
distributionUrl=https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened to me today with Android Studio 2.2 Beta2 on Windows 7 64-bit.

None of the solutions mentioned helped. Finally I was able to resolve the issue by re-importing my project.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to open Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle and check "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy over the /.gradle folder from a new Android project into the one that was having the problem. Then I restarted Android Studio and did a clean/build.  This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    After 1 hour R&D Not Solution as worked for me...

    But still i have solution follow this its work 100

    step 1: upgrade your build.gradle(Project:<your project name>)
    Example :  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3' // old gradle file
               classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1' // upgraded file 

                                OR
               classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

    Step 2 : Upgrade compileSdkVersion buildToolsVersion 
    Example : compileSdkVersion 23    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3 // old api's
              compileSdkVersion 25    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2" // upgraded api's

   Step 3:  upgrade gradle-wrapper.properties 

Example : distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip // old or any version

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip // new or any version
```

Step 4 : finally goto build>rebuild project...

......End @Ambilpura

Answer (score 0):

The answer is partially reduntant, but it's for those who are confused with what version of gradle distribution to add. 
It's the gradle version that's installed on your machine.

Ex: 
Check your gradle version by:
     "gradle -v" (mine was 5.4.1)

Update the file "your-app-project\your-app-name\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties" with
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

And done! It solved the problem for me.