# IntelliJ Gradle "Unable to find Method"

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

> ## The Error:
>
> Failed to sync Gradle project '-'
> Error:Unable to find method 'org.gradle.internal.logging.progress.DefaultProgressLoggerFactory.(Lorg/gradle/internal/logging/progress/ProgressListener;Lorg/gradle/internal/time/TimeProvider;)V'.

You can see, a constructor inside a class, which is found in the logging jar (gradle_home/lib/grade-logging-version.jar) is missing.
So, I think the Class-Path does not contain this jar file.

- Gradle Version: 3.5
- Running using the Command Line works.
- I have already tried this:

  - [Gradle sync failed: Unable to find method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655814/gradle-sync-failed-unable-)
  - to-find-method, it does not work for me.
  - I have tried to use different versions.
  - I can't see any difference when enabling

    - "Use default gradle wrapper"
    - "Use gradle wrapper task configuration"
    - "Use local gradle distribution".

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I am having the same issue with Android Studio 3.0 on Linux...

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem today.
The only way I was able to get it to work was to remove my IntelliJ IDEA IDE, get the latest from the website (with JDK) and put it in a new folder (i.e. no overwriting existing files).
After that, I deleted the .idea folder from the project and reimported it cleanly into the "new" IntelliJ.

I suspect upgrading IntelliJ from Version <= 2016.x caused the issue, since a new installation / clean extraction from archive caused it to work on the fly.

Comment: Yes, overwriting an existing installation caused the above issue for me with **Android Studio 3.0**.  Putting the IDE into a new directory is the solution.