# Android Project Gradle update from version 4.6 to 5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am updating my projects gradle from version 4.6 to 5.1 For the use of stripe 3ds2 as it is compulsory . i am getting this error while updating .

```
Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

i was reading this reference link `https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html#changes_4.7`

but couldn't find any help

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/50122867/10942972
Try this. I hope this will help you.

Comment: noop . the solution is to downgrade the gradle which i cannot for i have to use 5.1.1 in order for stripe to work .

Comment: If you downgrade, does it work (even if you remove Stripe)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a 

`./gradlew --stop
./gradlew clear -xdf # remove all not-checked-in files
./gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies # download all new`

helps ?

Comment: The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart). Maybe start with `./gradlew --stop`