# Android Studio Not Installing APK After Update to 3.6.x

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk

I just updated Android Studio from 3.5.x to 3.6.x. After the update I had to delete the .idea/* and .iml files in order for the build to work due to AS complaining about mixing Gradle and Non-Gradle files.

Since then, when I press "Run app", the Gradle build completes successfully and an apk is actually generated in the build/outputs/apk folder but the APK is not automatically installed on the running emulator. I have to drag and drop the .apk myself. Furthermore, when I manually run Build->Build APKs I get the message `Build APK(s): APK(s) generated successfully for 0 modules:`

Both the instant run and the "don't install APK if unchanged" settings have been disabled. I am using Gradle version 4.3 and the Android Gradle Plugin version 2.3.3

**Update: More recent versions than 3.6.x run fine again without any fixes on my part needed.** So I guess thanks, Google/Jetbrains.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade **`tools.build:gradle`** version

```
dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'

    }
```

Upgrade **`distributionUrl`** version. **`gradle-wrapper.properties`**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Then add below in App level **`build.gradle`** section.

```
 android {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
```

Then ***Clean-Rebuild-Restart IDE***.

Comment: When I update the tools.build:gradle version I get the error `Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V'.` when trying to sync the project.

Comment: @Max for this issue , check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122867/gradle-build-fails-unable-to-find-method-org-gradle-api-tasks-testing-test-get

Comment: @Max Solved this yet?

Comment: I got a few steps further but all ways led towards having to update gradle or the Android gradle plugin, which my codebase does not permit yet. However, even newer versions of Android Studio work without any problems, so I am currently running 4.0.