# Fail Gradle Build Project Ubuntu 16.04 Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

```
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
```

> org.gradle.api.Project.getPluginManager()Lorg/gradle/api/plugins/PluginManager;

Stacktrace

```
    Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'IoT-ConnectedCar'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:507)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.listener.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:90)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.Project.getPluginManager()Lorg/gradle/api/plugins/PluginManager;
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Kotlin2JvmSourceSetProcessor$doTargetSpecificProcessing$1.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:196)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Kotlin2JvmSourceSetProcessor$doTargetSpecificProcessing$1.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:125)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:105)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:94)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    ... 33 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in another question

Since this is a  stand-alone project upgrading the gradle version on my own machine was futile, so I had to go to to the gradle wrapper properties and edit the gradle version that was used.

The Steps are shown in details in the following link

[Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655814/gradle-sync-failed-unable-to-find-method)