# Gradle sync failed: Unable to find method org.gradle.api.artifacts.ProjectDependency.getProjectConfiguration()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I try to import an existing project in Android studio.

When importing it, i've got an Error with Gradle :

> Gradle sync failed: Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.ProjectDependency.getProjectConfiguration()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration;'

I tryed to : - Re-download dependencies and sync project : Fail (same error).

/build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.12.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' // google-services plugin

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "MyApp"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.2'
        roboVMVersion = '1.12.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    }
}
```

/app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.12.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' // google-services plugin

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Checkers"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.2'
        roboVMVersion = '1.12.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the answer by Shangwu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655814/gradle-sync-failed-unable-to-find-method

Answer (score 6):

1. Open the file under your-app-project\your-app-name\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
2. replace the old URL path by this one: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
3. Change the classpath of your-app-project\your-app-name\build.gradle to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

I use the latest version of Android Studio.