# Gradle sync failed: Unable to find method GradleBuild.getIncludedBuilds()

Tags: android, gradle

I have this error with Gradle and i try to solve it over and over but didn't work

I have seen the same problem in this Question

[Gradle sync failed: Unable to find method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655814/gradle-sync-failed-unable-to-find-method)

and i try to solve it by the answer of Shangwu but unfortunately didn't work
and i removed gradle and make android studio download it again but didn't work too same problem same error

this is my gradle setting

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

I have try to change it to 4.1 but didn't work same problem

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nightblue.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Top-level

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[image]

Edit:

I have update my android studio and i got a different log

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication'.


Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:944)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1600(DefaultConfiguration.java:120)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1285)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.getArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1257)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.execute(CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.java:42)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.execute(CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.java:29)
at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.resolveClassPath(DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.java:37)
at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.getScriptClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:72)
at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.defineScriptHandlerClassScope(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:204)
at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:82)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:184)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:64)
... 84 more
```

Comment: Did you try Re-Download?

Comment: can post your top level `build.gradle`? just want to check if you put `google()` in the proper place. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839

Comment: @Khemraj Yes i have try to re-download

Comment: @shizhen Check the update post

Comment: try to delete your `.gradle()` and `.m2` directories

Comment: @shizhen I have deleted .gradle folder and make android studio re-download it but didn't work, and i don't know where is .m2 give me the path

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your gradle, did you try (delete  `.idea`, `.gradle`, `.build` in project and app level)

Comment: @Khemraj I have make a 3 new projects so if the problem in the project it can be solve but didn't work too

Comment: Try Delete `C:\Users\yourUserName\.gradle`

Comment: @Khemraj I deleted before and he download it again but same problem i don't know why!

Comment: All your project are showing same problem?

Comment: @Khemraj Yes all projects

Comment: What is your Android Studio version?

Comment: @Khemraj 3.0.1.

Comment: Can try updating it to latest 3.2.1, because I can not see another option.

Comment: @Khemraj okay i will try

Comment: @Khemraj Same problem but with a different log

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle version and gradle wrapper setting should match

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Android Gradle Plugin version: **classpath**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' // this is your AGP version.
        ...
    }
}
```

Close Android Studio and delete your maven cache directory `.m2` which is usually under your PC home directory, on macOS it is under `~/` for example. And delete your gradle cache directory which is also usually under your home directory.

Then open your Android Studio to **re-synchronise** your project.