# Can't run project with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I cloned an Android Studio [project](https://github.com/ashwanijanghu/ExoPlayer-Offline) an tried to run it. When I open the project for the first time I get a message telling me that Android Studio was `"unable to get gradle wrapper properties"`. If I try to compile the project I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.ProjectDependency.getProjectConfiguration()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration;'.
```

Do you have an idea about the problem? I am using `Android Studio 3.3` under mac OS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655814/gradle-sync-failed-unable-to-find-method

Answer (score 0):

Some developers are facing some problems Android Studio 3.3 currently.. 
I would recommend to invalidate caches/restart.