# My gradle build failed after I imported volley library

Tags: android, gradle

I have implemented phone number detection and SMS verification functionality into my project by referring to this project
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=android%2Fidentity-samples%2Fidentity-samples-master%2FSmsVerification%2Fapp%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fsamples%2Fsmartlock%2Fsms_verify%2Fui%2FPhoneNumberActivity.java#

I downloaded and imported volley from the link below
https://github.com/google/volley

I am getting an error while building my project, please guide me I am new to  android studio...

**Error**

```
Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publication.MavenPublicationInternal.getPublishableFiles()Lorg/gradle/api/file/FileCollection;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Update:
I deleted gradle file from C:\Users\MY PC.gradle\wrapper\dists and rebuilt the project and now I am getting this error

> Error Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the
> proxy settings in Gradle. Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync
> project Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle

Comment: does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442901/gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-sometimes-occurs-after-a-network)  can solve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

change the distributionUrl in the gradle-wrapper.properties to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip` to get the build running again. This seems to be a similar problem [Gradle sync failed: Unable to find method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655814/gradle-sync-failed-unable-to-find-method)